# Who is "Old Nicky" in The Son by Philipp Meyer?

Tags: meaning

In Chapter 67, Eli McCullough thinks:

> I started to tell her, but couldn't. Old Nicky himself had pinched my jaw shut.

Who is Old Nicky? I suspect it's some folklore, but can't find anything on him.

Answer (score 10):

*Old Nick* is a slang term for the devil. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Old%20Nick):

> **Old Nick** noun
>
> — used as a name of the devil
>
> Example sentences:
>
> - *he gave me a look that would scare **Old Nick***

So Eli is claiming that the devil made him keep his jaw shut.